# Anonymous user getting user name as logged in but session expired

Tags: proxies, caching

Logged in to drupal site and after some time logged out from site. Then visiting pages as anonymous user. But one of the page is displaying some user name as logged in even though user session expired. All other pages are working fine but only single page getting this issue. Enabled Varnish/Memcache on server. Any resolution for this..

Comment: I'd guess your Varnish config is wrong

Comment: what 'single page' exactly is this happening on?